# Can't start Ubuntu - Package power limit notification

Tags: kernel, startup, cpu

I used Ubuntu 12.10 on my current laptop for a couple of weeks without problems... Now there is no way to start it.

When I try to boot Ubuntu during the startup process I get this error:

```
[CPU0]: Package power limit notification (total events = 1)
[CPU2]: Package power limit notification (total events = 1)
[CPU1]: Package power limit notification (total events = 1)
[CPU3]: Package power limit notification (total events = 1)
```

And it's like I can't do anything.
I'm on a Sony Vaio laptop and the CPU model is: Intel Core i7-3520M CPU @ 2.90GHz

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? And what happens if you try to boot an older kernel (hold Shift when Grub is loading to select)?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that.. The version is 12.10 and when I try an older kernel looks like sometimes I get the same error and sometimes it starts in low graphic mode.

Comment: It seems more people are having the same error, on [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1785211), with no solution so far. Maybe for now it should be better to stick with an older kernel.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:**
>
> - Power Limit Notification is a feature that was added to the Sandy Bridge processors from Intel. The notification does not indicate a
>     problem, and should not be reported as a Critical-level message.
> - The occurrence of the power limit notification is routine, and the system should not be reporting the messages. They can be ignored.

**source:** [Linux - "Package Power limit" and "Core power limit" notifications](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN266056/EN).

**Possible solutions are:**

- Upgrade kernel (or downgrade if upgrade not possible)
- Clear PLN flag by adding `clearcpuid=229` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` then `sudo update-grub`
- Set the machine's Performance Profile to Max Performance in the BIOS, if that setting is available

**References:**

- [Linux - "Package Power limit" and "Core power limit" notifications](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN266056/EN)
- [Kernel 3.6.2 Power Regressions (Sandy Bridge)](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=150743)

Answer (score 0):

May be Boot-repair will fix this problem.
Follow the procedure Mentioned here "https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair" Or "[Can't boot into ubuntu after remove window7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230918/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-after-remove-window7)"
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Get the [Boot-Repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) or if it fails [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) iso/image and boot from it.

Remark : you can also install the ISO on a live-USB (eg via UnetBootin or LiliUSB or Universal USB Installer).