# Can't boot into ubuntu after remove window7

Tags: 12.10, boot, windows-8

My friend have a computer pre-installing window 7,but later he installed other systems including window 8,and linux. All worked fine with the `grub2` for a few weeks.

Yesterday,when he removed window 7 and restart computer all worked fine.
But later he remove the partition where window7 formally located he can't boot any more just showing `grub rescue`.Run `ls (hd0,msdosX)` command,but all partitions are showing `unknown filesystem`.So he tried install a liveCD and mistakenly run a memory test which was terminated by him in the half of the process.

Later,I try to boot using LiveCD ubuntu 12.10,but when boot it,it just showing
`SYSLINUX 4.03 2010-10-22 EDD Copyright (C) 1994-2010 H. Peter Anvin et al`
This liveCD is fine and worked for me few days ago,then I try to boot using USB
`SYSLINUX 4.05 2012-10-22 EDD Copyright (C) 1994-2012 H. Peter Anvin et al`
 similar information displayed. What should I do?Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I don't think it was the memory test that caused this, whether interrupted or not.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ maybe boot loader was corrupted,I just think that i should try to offer enough information ;)

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your Partition table is bonked.

Try using Testdisk with a live cd

- http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

To reconfigure grub from a live cd, use this excellent HOWTO

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1581099

Answer (score 0):

if you have windows geinstalleerdt as first and then ubuntu. The bootloaders are on the windows partition. so the user can choose in the beginning witch Operating system it wants.

if you removed the windows partition. You permanently delete de bootloader of ubuntu too. so best option is to complete clean install.

Answer (score 0):

Check where the boot partition is located. Windows 7 makes a 100M partition for booting. After removing Windows 7 and adding Windows 8 this partition tends to get changed. As far as I know it is still NTFS based.

There is a thread on how to restore the boot partition over at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader that you should read. You need a CD or DVD that can boot and follow their instructions. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm too late to answer to this thread. But follow this step when you format Windows partition after installing Ubuntu. You can do this with working Internet connection. Boot from Ubuntu live CD or Ubunt USB boot and select try Ubuntu. And open terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T And install this Boot-Repair software by typing "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update" 
2. After it finish installing type "sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair &" and press enter. For detailed information visit this url "https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair" 
You can also install it by preparing boot-repair cd or download iso file form this link "http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/" 
After installing Select Option "Recommanded Repair" 
Note down the URL appeared after repair completes for getting further help
Mention that URL in the forum to get specific help if the above Recommanded Repair doesn't correct repair your grub. I hope this will help you next time.